# Unexplainable MySQL Error #1064 for Empty String On creating After Update Trigger?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I was running MySQL with Server Version: 10.1.34-MariaDB (Distributed within XAmpp 7.2.7-0-VC15-installer) on Windows 8.1 machine, using PhpMyadmin on Google Chrome to access Mysql database and i got this error :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

for this create trigger syntax :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Tsopd_main_AfterUpdate;
CREATE TRIGGER Tsopd_main_AfterUpdate AFTER UPDATE
ON sopd_main FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET @jns = 1;
END
```

When i changed the code like this :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Tsopd_main_AfterUpdate;
CREATE TRIGGER Tsopd_main_AfterUpdate AFTER UPDATE
ON sopd_main FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

END
```

or like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Tsopd_main_AfterUpdate;
CREATE TRIGGER Tsopd_main_AfterUpdate AFTER UPDATE
ON sopd_main FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
-- SET @jns = 1;
END
```

it worked.

Can anybody Help me to show me what is wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `DELIMITER` directive to change the query delimiter, so you can use `;` inside the trigger definition.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Tsopd_main_AfterUpdate$$
CREATE TRIGGER Tsopd_main_AfterUpdate AFTER UPDATE
ON sopd_main FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET @jns = 1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I didn't see that coming.